Using pdflscape within a list / environment
I'm working on a document with description environments that are several pages long. Some of these pages contain tikzpictures that are rotated using \rotatebox. I'm looking for a way to tell pdf viewers to display these pages rotated.
Using the landscape environment from pdflscape (instead of \rotatebox) outside of environments works well.
However, using the landscape environment within a description environment or similar causes an unwanted large bottom / left margin.
It seems this problem is not restricted to the description environment as seen here and here. All solutions I've found do not work within environments or place the page number on the new bottom instead of leaving it at the new left side of the page.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item \rotatebox{90}{I'd like to have this page rotated in a pdf viewer without changing anything else.}
    \begin{landscape}
        Using landscape inside description causes a huge left margin.
    \end{landscape}
\end{description}

\end{document}


The landscape environment is not suited: that rotates full pages. The rotation in the PDF viewer is done by adding an attribute to the page, the main problem is here to revert the setting again for the next page. With the PDF management this is quite straightforward (it needs two compilations):
\DocumentMetadata{} %loads pdf management.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\rotatethispage{\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{ThisPage}{Rotate}{90}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{description}
    \item \rotatebox{90}{I'd like to have this page rotated in 
          a pdf viewer without changing anything else.}%
          \rotatethispage
            
        Using landscape inside description causes a huge left margin.    
\end{description}
\lipsum
\end{document}

